# How to use environment variable set from docker-compose.yml into package.json?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have an environment variable inside my docker-compose file. For example, it reads:

```
environment:
  - STORYBOOK_PORT=9000
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "storybook": "start-storybook -p ${storybook_port} -c .storybook --ci"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
"scripts": {
  "storybook": "start-storybook -p ${STORYBOOK_PORT} -c .storybook --ci"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "envsubst < package.json.template > package.json; "]

Add the script in Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Create any environment variable in docker-compose you want, then
where you want to add environment variable use

```
${variable_name}
```

Then,

> envsubst < ./package.json

, it will replace environment variable with its value.

Comment: you can use | pipe to run command with it like this one.
envsubst < ./package.json | command -f